# query (package seqinr): Error

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am learning bioinformatics using this link:
http://a-little-book-of-r-for-bioinformatics.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/chapter3.html
I use R 3.0.3 and R studio and while runing the code below I get an error, why?

```
library("seqinr")    
choosebank("refseqViruses")
query("Dengue1", "AC=NC_001477")
attributes(Dengue1)
Error: object 'Dengue1' not found
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Im not sure if it helps (I have not used the 'seqinr' package before I saw this question) but have you tried calling the 'attributes()' function with quotes?

```
> choosebank("refseqViruses")
> query("Dengue1", "AC=NC_001477")
> attributes(Dengue1)
Error: object 'Dengue1' not found
```

vs:

```
> attributes("Dengue1")
NULL
```

That 'NULL' refers to an empty object, so perhaps try it with another accession id?

Hope that helps.

- EDIT:

When you save the query to a variable and call 'attributes()' on it, it supports an empty object:

```
> d1<-query("Dengue1", "AC=NC_001477")
> attributes(d1)
$names
[1] "call"     "name"     "nelem"    "typelist" "req"      "socket" 
$class
[1] "qaw"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it before and I saw it works. Theregfire is it valid?

Comment: No problem. What you mean by 'Theregfire'? Also, if my solution helped you please click on the check mark on my post.

Comment: My error. I wanted to know if it is valid and I do not loose information due to the new variable.